# Calculating the survival rate of a group with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have DataFrame in Python like this:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"Sex":["male", "male", "female", "male"],
                "Survived":[0,0,1,1]})
```

And I would like to calculate how huge percent of "male" survived "1". So I need code which will take from DataFrame all Sex= "male" and Survived = 1 divide it by all Sex="male"

My expected output is: 1/3 = 0,3333

Comment: can you show your expected output and what you have attempted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can first filter the data frame for male candidates, and then calculate the average here, since the `Survived` column only consists out of `0`s and `1`s:

```
>>> df.loc[df['Sex'] == 'male', 'Survived'].mean()
0.3333333333333333
```

Or if you want the survival percentage per gender, we can perform a group by:

```
>>> df.groupby('Sex')['Survived'].mean()
Sex
female    1.000000
male      0.333333
Name: Survived, dtype: float64
```

So 100% of the females (well 1/1) survived, whereas 33.33% of the males (1/3) survived.